# Visual Studio 2003 GUI in japanese

Tags: unicode, internationalization, windows-forms-designer, visual-studio-2003

I have an application developed in C++ in Visual Studio 2003 (Windows Forms application). My requirement is such that some of the text of the GUI of the application has to be in Japanese and some other in English. I am copping the Japanese text from the Google language tool and pasting in the main menu bar text in the form. Doing this is giving me small squares instead of actual Japanese text. However, when I am pasting thise text in a Word file, the characters are printing correctly.

How do I resolve this issue of multi-language GUI in Visual Studio 2003 (Windows Forms application)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a font on your form that supports Far Eastern glyphs, such as a [Shift JIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) font. Check what font Word uses for the pasted text, and see if you can set your form and controls to use that same font.

Comment: Thanks for reply... Can you please give me some detail how to use SHIFT-JIS font in menu bar in Visual Studio 2003.Can you provide some helpful link.

Comment: Select the menu strip by clicking any of its entries, and view the properties of it (it acts just like a control). One of those properties is Font, where you can change to any font installed on your system. You will, however, have to make sure the target system has the same font or at least one recognised as in the same family.

Comment: Thanks for reply... Yes the font property is given in the menustrip(like File menu) in Visual Studio 2010 but not in Visual Studio 2003.. Is there any way to change font in Visual Studio 2003?

Comment: If it isn't in the properties list in 2003 then I'm afraid it probably isn't a supported property of that version of the .NET framework... You could try 'myMenuStrip.Font = ' at form load time but I suspect it will throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. Yes I have tried that but that was giving error. I will have to create that application in higher version of Visual Studio.